# How can I fix this flutter Installations error

Tags: flutter

BITS Transfer                                                                                                              This is a file transfer that uses the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS).                                   [                                                                                  ]                                                                                                                                  Transferring

ِAfter I insert in command flutter --version
This message was popping up

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is downloading the latest flutter sdk so, let it complete .it will take nearly 15 minutes to download .